# Map a JSON field (to a value) based on another field (which is a key) using Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization, objectmapper

```
{
  "key1": {
    "parameter1": "String1",
    "parameter2": "String2"
  },
  "key2": {
    "parameter1": "String3",
    "parameter2": "String4"
  },
  "key3": {
    "parameter1": "String5",
    "parameter2": "String6"
  }
}
```

I have the above `JSON` (/Users/user1/Desktop/responseMap.json) which is basically a `Map<String, MockResponse>` where `MockResponse` is the below `POJO`:

```
public class MockResponse {
    public String parameter1;
    public String parameter2;
}
```

Now, I have another `POJO` - `TestCase`, and another `JSON` - `testCase.json` as below:

```
public class TestCase {

    public String responseMapFileLocation;
    public String mockResponseKey;
    public MockResponse mockResponse;
}
```

testCase.json

```
{
  "responseMapFileLocation": "/Users/user1/Desktop/responseMap.json",
  "mockResponseKey": "key1",
  "mockResponse": null
}
```

What I am able to do is first map `testCase.json` to `TestCase` using `Jackson`, then map `responseMap.json` to `Map<String, MockResponse>`, then in my code search for `mockResponseKey` in the map.

But what I want to do is when I map `testCase.json` to `TestCase` using `Jackson`, I want the value of variable `mockResponse` to set automatically based on the value of variable `mockResponseKey` using the first `JSON` map.

Comment: The above json is of type Map, check how to map to map for a json.

Comment: If adding libraries is an option, `ModelMapper` is worth a look.

Comment: @Pankaj I have posted an answer have a look let m eknow if it works for you

Comment: Have you solved this issue? Did below answers were helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write custom deserialiser for `TestCase` class. In custom deserialiser you can parse basic properties: `responseMapFileLocation`, `mockResponseKey` and load `mockResponse` from other file. To deserialiser `MockResponse` you can use new `ObjectMapper` instance. Below code shows how this concept could be implemented:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.TreeNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.MapType;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(jsonFile, TestCase.class));
    }
}

class MockResponse {
    public String parameter1;
    public String parameter2;
}

@JsonDeserialize(using = TestCaseFromExternalFileDeserializer.class)
class TestCase {

    public String responseMapFileLocation;
    public String mockResponseKey;
    public MockResponse mockResponse;
}

class TestCaseFromExternalFileDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<TestCase> {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper;
    private final MapType mapType;

    public TestCaseFromExternalFileDeserializer() {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructMapType(Map.class, String.class, MockResponse.class);
    }

    @Override
    public TestCase deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        TreeNode treeNode = p.readValueAsTree();

        TestCase testCase = new TestCase();
        testCase.responseMapFileLocation = ((JsonNode) treeNode.get("responseMapFileLocation")).asText();
        testCase.mockResponseKey = ((JsonNode) treeNode.get("mockResponseKey")).asText();
        parseMockResponse(testCase);

        return testCase;
    }

    private void parseMockResponse(TestCase testCase) throws IOException {
        Map<String, MockResponse> map = mapper.readValue(new File(testCase.responseMapFileLocation), mapType);

        testCase.mockResponse = map.get(testCase.mockResponseKey);
    }
}
```

You need to implement only `toString` method for each `POJO` class. Above code prints:

```
TestCase{responseMapFileLocation='./resource/responseMap.json', mockResponseKey='key1', mockResponse=MockResponse{parameter1='String1', parameter2='String2'}}
```

Both `JSON` files are in `resource` folder.

See also:

- [How use jackson ObjectMapper inside custom deserializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551983/how-use-jackson-objectmapper-inside-custom-deserializer)
- [Jackson Streaming API](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-streaming-api) - if you want to implement `MockResponse` deserialisation in faster way.

Answer (score 1):

Tweaking the getter setter in your Test class and marking the field as private I was able to make it dynamic (Imports are from `org.codehaus.jackson` package)

```
class TestCase {

    private String responseMapFileLocation;

    private String mockResponseKey;

    @JsonIgnore
    private MockResponse mockResponse; //else value will be override in json value

    public String getResponseMapFileLocation() {
        return responseMapFileLocation;
    }
    public void setResponseMapFileLocation(String responseMapFileLocation) {
        this.responseMapFileLocation = responseMapFileLocation;
    }
    public String getMockResponseKey() {
        return mockResponseKey;
    }
    public void setMockResponseKey(String mockResponseKey1) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, MockResponse> map = mapper.readValue(new File("C:\\Users\\Json1.json"), TypeFactory.mapType(HashMap.class, String.class, MockResponse.class));
        this.mockResponse = map.get(mockResponseKey1);
        this.mockResponseKey = mockResponseKey1;
    }
    public MockResponse getMockResponse() {
        return mockResponse;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TestCase [responseMapFileLocation=" + responseMapFileLocation + ", mockResponseKey=" + mockResponseKey
                + ", mockResponse=" + mockResponse + "]";
    }
}


class MockResponse {
    public String parameter1;
    public String parameter2;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MockResponse [parameter1=" + parameter1 + ", parameter2=" + parameter2 + "]";
    }
}
```

and Running below code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        TestCase testCase = mapper.readValue(new File("C:\\UsersJson2.json"), TestCase.class);
        System.out.println(testCase);

    }
```

output will be

```
TestCase [responseMapFileLocation=/Users/user1/Desktop/responseMap.json, mockResponseKey=key1, mockResponse=MockResponse [parameter1=String1, parameter2=String2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is not possible with just Jackson. Jackson is primarily a marshalling/unmarshalling tool, converting JSONs to Objects and vice versa. In other words, the value of the object must be known at the time of unmarshalling.

However you can unmarshal your json as a HashMap using the code:

```
new JSONObject(map);
```

search for the MockResponse-as-a-string using the mockResponseKey and then unmarshal that code into a new MockResponse.